# How do I pass variables to JVM that are referenced in .property file?

Tags: java, variables, junit, intellij-idea

I have following in my .properties file:

```
connection1.username=${cloud.db.username}
connection1.password=${cloud.db.password}
```

I'd like to pass these variables in Run/Debug Configuration

I thought all I need to do is to pass following parameters in JVM command line: `-Dcloud.db.username=JOHN -Dcloud.db.password=SECRET`.

But in the code call to `Properties.getProperty()` still returns `${cloud.db.username}`.

I'm running it as junit under IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Passing properties into a jvm using -D puts them into the system properties (accessed via System.getProperties()).

Creating a java.util.Properties from a file in code gives you a completely separate set of properties.

Lots of applications allow you to specify properties via the command line -D option and in a file.  To do this they have to implement some sort of fallback mechanism between the two and decide which gets preference.

Also, some applications allow you to define a property as referring to another, they generally do this either by extending or wrapping java.util.Properties.

You're expecting both of these things to work but neither are provided by Java out of the box.

If you want to implement these features, take a look at some open source projects that support them.

Answer (score 2):

I don't fully understand why would you want to do something like that. Why do you need those values in the property file if you are not really using it?

If you want to pass those two parameters as custom command line parameters (-D) then can't you just do:

```
System.getProperty("cloud.db.username");
System.getProperty("cloud.db.password");
```

Comment: well I've been wondering whether to post this answer for some time. Thought (well I still do) it was tricky and that I'm missing something ;)

Answer (score 1):

The value for `connection1.username` will alway be `"${cloud.db.username}"`, java does not replace it with the value of another property or an environment variable.

If you want such a replacement, then you'll have to implement it (iterate through the entire value set of the properties object and replace all values, that match this pattern with the values of the referenced properties)

Answer (score 0):

Trying accessing them via `System.getProperty(...)` instead